# Linux Hard Drive Partitioning

Tags: centos, partition, hard-disk

I've decided to do a fresh Linux CentOS 6 install onto a small computer which I intend to use as a basic server.

The OS has been installed and I would like to partition the 31gig sda drive (there is only one hard drive in it) into 2 15gig partitions sda and sdb.

I have never needed to partition a hard drive on linux before and I am taking a look at the tool parted (I have booted into rescue mode btw).

```
# parted /dev/sda
# print
```

I get the following output

```
Number   Start    End      Size     Type      File system   Flags
1        1049kb   525MB    524MB    primary   ext4          boot
2        525MB    32.2GB   31.7GB   primary                 lvm
```

I'd like to get advice on how to correctly partition the 31GB hard drive into the two 15GB hard drives without breaking the system (I have done this before many times and I don't entirely trust the googled instructions I have found)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you are quite lucky, because the second partition is a logical volume manager [lvm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvm) partition for which it is easier to reduce, extend, add and delete logical partitions [as described here](http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/lvm.html).

Basically you have to follow the steps described in the [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163969/resize-root-lvm-and-fs-in-debian-7), which does extend the logical volume. Instead of extending you would shrink/reduce it. Checkout the manpages for:

- [resize2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) for resizing the filesystem on the lvm partition
- [lvrreduce](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvreduce) for reducing the lvm partiton
- [lvcreate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvcreate) to add a new 15GB lvm partition

Comment: Hi bejamin, thanks for taking a look at my question. Those answers looked good but I need to do it using the CentOS parted tool. It does have the option to resize a partition but I need to give it the format `# resize 2 *start place* *end place*` both places required in MB

Comment: okay of parted try this: `resize 2 525MB 15525MB` which should give you a round about 15 GB partition. Tho I do not understand why you have to use parted if you just can use LVM. Oh btw. you will not get sbd since this would be a new pysical disk.

Comment: wait parted doesn't work because it has no filesystem, but if i use df -h I can't see the right partitions because I'm in linux rescue, should I not be in linux rescue?

Comment: Sorry I was confused about the parted utility, should I be logged in as normal to be partitioning the main hard drive?

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot, I missed out a step, a very stupid step

Comment: Okay @Trent it seem that you need to rephrase your questions into: What do you want to have? Going from general (A running server os) to specific (/usr should be on a partition on its own). I guess you just want a running system with CentOS. So I would recommend you to keep everything on one partition, especially since your HDD is quite small anyways.

Comment: I'm going to create a new question without the assumptions, thanks for your help benjamin

Comment: @Trent okay. Do not forget to mark the question as answered.